# How to use webauthn with iOS and react?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, webauthn, face-id

```
if (navigator.credentials && window.PublicKeyCredential) {
      const available = await window.PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable();
      if (available) {
        const newCredentialInfo = await navigator.credentials.create(options);
        var response = newCredentialInfo.response;

        var clientExtensionsResults = newCredentialInfo.getClientExtensionResults();
        alert(JSON.stringify(response))
        alert(JSON.stringify(clientExtensionsResults));
      }
      else {
        alert("Unsupported");
      }
    }
```

gives me to use private key only (usb or smthg. But if I use this `options.publicKey` with JavaScript and html, everything is ok. It offers me to use FaveID to auth, but response is empty.

My options are

```
{"rp":{"id":"https://im-faceid.netlify.app","name":"netlify.app"},"user":{"id":{"0":97,"1":87,"2":120,"3":53,"4":89,"5":87,"6":49,"7":118,"8":99,"9":109,"10":82,"11":104,"12":99,"13":50,"14":57,"15":50},"name":"test","displayName":"Test User"},"challenge":{"0":79,"1":72,"2":78,"3":122,"4":101,"5":71,"6":86,"7":111},"pubKeyCredParams":[{"type":"public-key","alg":-7}],"authenticatorSelection":{"authenticatorAttachment":"platform","requireResidentKey":false,"userVerification":"required"},"attestation":"none","timeout":15000}
```

Comment: And for that matter what model iPhone, and version of iOS is it running? And do you have a link to something public we can see the issue ourselves on?

Comment: iPhone 11 Pro Max with the latest firmware (14.4). Yes, I deployed the latest build to https://im-faceid.netlify.app

Comment: You're going to need to update the site to set the value of `rp.id` in your options to `im-faceid.netlify.app` (get rid of the `https://`, that values needs to be just a domain, not an entire URL) to get things working. That will get the site testable on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're calling `navigator.credentials.create()` in your `<App />` component's `componentDidMount()`. macOS and iOS Safari both require that WebAuthn API calls **that want to use Touch ID** *must* be made as a result of a "user gesture":

> The amount of unsolicited prompts has been surprisingly low. The situation is different with the release of Face ID and Touch ID for the web. **So, Face ID and Touch ID for the web require user gestures to function.** (User gestures are not required for security keys for backward compatibility.)

See Apple's introduction of their support for WebAuthn for more guidance: https://webkit.org/blog/11312/meet-face-id-and-touch-id-for-the-web/

If you update your React code to move the logic that calls `navigator.credentials.create()` into, say, a button click handler, you'll be able to use Face ID. It'll require you click a button to trigger WebAuthn instead of just loading the page, but that's the reality of working with WebAuthn on an Apple OS.

Comment: Hm, probably, you’re right. My another code written in simple JavaScript and html uses button to unit this process. In react I forgot to test it. I tried several variants in `rp.id` even `domain.name`